# Can Teleport be set up to be automated?

Tags: macos, ios, system-settings, screen-sharing

I've got two Macs, and I only use one keyboard and mouse thanks to Teleport. The problem is that I have to activate it every time I turn my computer on. Would it be possible to do it automatically?

Comment: I deleted the second question since we allow people to ask questions for free and we prefer one question per question.

Comment: No problem, I'll ask another question then.

Comment: Can't you add it to Login Items under Users & Groups?

Comment: No, because it's not an application. It's a ".prefPane".